# why do I got this error saying that can't write to “pageid_indexid.txt”?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I try to do my homework on classifying texts, I got this error：

```
“Error occures when open file C:\Windows\system32\pageid_indexid.txt for write!”
```

I looked into C:\Windows\system32 and found that there is no such a file, then I create one myself but I still get this error.
When I try to run my program on other computer, it works fine.
Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Comment: That folder is a system folder and writing to it is really a bad idea. Surely you don't have the permissions (rightly) to write there. I suggest to write your file elsewhere

Comment: I didn't write this program, I just have to use it and try different parameters of KNN. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run as Admin will solve it. Besides, maybe we are classmates.

Answer (score 0):

It's a system folder. You don't have the permissions to manipulate this file.
If you really want to write something in this file, check that the VS runs under admin.
Also, the app that will work with this file, should be run under admin too.

Comment: I tried to run it under admin, it works! Thank you very much!:-)